# How to tell if a pandas date time difference is null?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I need to fill in missing dates in a `pandas` data frame.  The dataframe consists of weekly sales data for multiple items.  I am looping through each item to see if there are missing weeks of dates with the intention of filling in those dates with a '0' for sales and all other information copied down.

I use the following code to find the missing dates:

```
pd.date_range(start="2017-01-13", end="2022-12-16", freq = "W-SAT").difference(df_['week_date'])
```

While I can print the missing dates and search manually for the few items that are missing sales weeks, I have not found a way to do this programmatically.

I tried

```
for item in df['ord_base7'].unique():
df_ = df[df['ord_base7'] == item]
if pd.date_range(start="2017-01-13", end="2022-12-16", freq = "W-SAT").difference(df_['week_date']).isnan() == True:
    pass
else:
    print(item, pd.date_range(start="2017-01-13", end="2022-12-16", freq = "W-SAT").difference(df_['week_date']))
```

That yielded the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_55320/2582723605.py in <module>
      1 for item in df['ord_base7'].unique():
      2     df_ = df[df['ord_base7'] == item]
----> 3     if pd.date_range(start="2017-01-13", end="2022-12-16", freq = "W-SAT").difference(df_['week_date']).isnan() == True:
      4         pass
      5     else:

AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'isnan'
```

How can I program a way to see if there are no dates missing so those items can be passed over?

Comment: I just posed an answer. Please let me know if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind... I just tried the following and it worked.

```
for item in df['ord_base7'].unique():
df_ = df[df['ord_base7'] == item]
if pd.date_range(start="2017-01-13", end="2022-12-16", freq = "W-SAT").difference(df_['week_date']).empty == True:
    pass
else:
    print(item, pd.date_range(start="2017-01-13", end="2022-12-16", freq = "W-SAT").difference(df_['week_date']))
```

The `.empty` is how to do this with a date time index.

Answer (score 0):

Looping on a pandas dataframe is not a good idea because it's inefficient. Just use the `.fillna()` and pass in whatever value you want to be set instead of NaN:

```
df['week_date'].fillna(0)
```

Comment: There is no missing value though.  The dates just aren't there.  That's why I have to use the date_range to find the values that are missing but that's not a dataframe.

Comment: What do you mean by "The dates just aren't there"? Your missing values must be of some dtype and have some values. Can you show an example of your data?

Comment: I mean that the dates are missing from the data frame.  So I have to find the dates which is what the `pd.date_range...` line is for.

Comment: I think by missing values you mean time gaps. Because missing values are the term used for `NaN` or `null`.